# How do I organise my data in Google SpreadSheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have separate sheets based on month's of the year.

[image: sheets]

Each time I create a new month I copy the template sheet and fill in the data.
Therefore each sheet has the same layout it's only the data that changes.

I'm getting to the point where I would interested in the data over two months combined, right now I would have to go into sheet 1 (Feb-2015) and copy the field say B2 (say it's 5) then go into sheet 2 (March-2015) and copy B2 (it is 7) then add them together, 5 + 7 = 12.

There must be a better way of doing this? Can I combine all of the sheets then create some type of selector for the month? I'm not sure what to do and also not sure what 'spreadsheet keywords' I need to Google to find what I want?

Comment: I also found this https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the data for all the months into ONE sheet.   Use a column called Month to keep track of what month each row is for.

When you want to see one month's data only, click in the data area, then choose Data > Filter from the menus.  This puts a small drop-down arrow in the header cells, by clicking on this you can control what filters are applied.

There is an example of this approach here:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ro-wEdk-Gvw0v-UltYlbjf4EMLq5sPeJYhM1zKMblt4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: but at the moment I have 20 rows (peoples names) so if I add a column for `month` this would mean I'd have duplicate rows for each persons name? which I don't want.. or will I have to

Comment: There is no problem with having duplicate rows for each persons name.    If you put the data into format (what I have described), then you can filter on any column, any time you need to.   And you can also use other features like pivot tables to make summaries that only have one row for each person, and put other fields (like Month) into the Columns section.     But the way your data is organised now, you cannot use any of these features.

Comment: What you say works, but if I want data from 3 months of the year, I still have to do this calculation manually my self

Comment: No, you can use a pivot table, and select which three months to display.